# Search mongodb with parenthesis in the regex search argument

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have searched similar problems but I did not find a solution

```
const keyword = "test("

db.auto_complete.find({keyword:{$regex: new Reg Exp('^'+keyword) }})
```

if variable keyword does not container a `(` it works
But if the variable keyword includes a `(` I get the error

> Invalid regular expression: /^test(/ : Unterminated group

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to escape the parentheses with a `\`. Otherwise it Regex will interpret it as an operator used for matching or grouping.

```
const keyword = "test\("
```